# UrlFetchApp.fetch(url) intermittent "Unexpected error"

Tags: google-apps-script

In order to check HTTP service status I've wrote script that goes through spreadsheet and for a list of URLs checks if they are Up or Down, script is time driven every five minutes.

I have rare intermittent "Unexpected error" errors from UrlFetchApp.fetch(url) and from
time to time there are DNS and Timeout errors that will go away if I repeat request after few seconds.

No few actual questions if someone can help:
 I've used Utilities.sleep(5000) to pause for 5 seconds,
 is that OK or there are better ways to wait and
 try to fetch again after few seconds?

Why do I get "Unexpected error" even if I repeat request after 5 seconds, when script is
 run again after five minutes there is no "Unexpected error" !?

How could I improve code below?

Actual script:

```
/* 
Periodically check status of web sites :-)
Google Apps for Busines UrlFetch daily limit is 100.000 requests,

Algorithm
  read site and old status from sheet
  check site and set new status  
  if status changed send email (+sms in future by using twilio)
  update status in spreadsheet

"Site, Status code, Time of last change, Last error description"
*/
function main() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() ;
  var currentRow, oldStatusCode, newStatusCode ;
  var url, response, err, subject, message ; 
  var today = new Date() ;

  currentRow = 2
  while ((url = sheet.getRange(currentRow, 1).getValue()) != "") {
    oldStatusCode = sheet.getRange(currentRow, 2).getValue() ;
    newStatusCode = "Ok"
    subject = "mCheck: " + url + " Up Status Change!" ;  
    message = url + " Up Status Change!" + "\n Time: " + today.toUTCString() ;

    var tries = 3 ; // Check at least three times that status changed and it is not a one time glitch
    do {
      try {
        response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url) ;
      } catch (err) {
      newStatusCode = "Down"
      sheet.getRange(currentRow, 4).setValue(err.message) ;
      subject = "mCheck: " + url + " Down Status Change!" ;  
      message = url + " Down Status Change!" + "\n Error message: " + err.message + "\n Time: " + today.toUTCString() ;
      if (err.message.indexOf("Unexpected") > -1) { // If UrlFetch failed on Google side just ignore this iteration...
        newStatusCode = oldStatusCode ;
      }
    }
    if (oldStatusCode != newStatusCode) { // In case of status change wait 5 seconds before trying again
      Utilities.sleep(5000) ;
    }
    --tries ;
  } while ((oldStatusCode != newStatusCode) && tries >= 0)

  if (oldStatusCode != newStatusCode) {
    sheet.getRange(currentRow, 2).setValue(newStatusCode) ;
    sheet.getRange(currentRow, 3).setValue(today.toUTCString()) ;
    if (oldStatusCode != "") {
      MailApp.sendEmail(email_to, subject, message) ;
    }
  }
  ++currentRow;
 }
```

}

Comment: I have written a Google Apps script for the same purpose and am being hit by the same issue. If you found a solution for this please post it here. I will keep looking elsewhere...

Comment: It seems other people are seeing this as well. https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2758 https://code.google.com/p/gmail-delay-send/issues/detail?id=60

Comment: I think starring issue [2758](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2758) (Thanks, Rafael!) is our best option right now to get Google attention on this problem.

Comment: The Apps Script team has recently completed several internal changes that should significantly reduce the number of timeout and 'unexpected' errors caused when running UrlFetch from a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a [muteHttpExceptions parameter](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)) for to catch failures. The fetch will not throw an exception if the response code indicates failure, and will instead return the HTTPResponse.

**Sample**

```
var params = {muteHttpExceptions:true};
response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
```

And you may [use a cURL](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content#serving_json_from_scripts) or analoge for a sheldue.

**Sample**

cURL. Set this at a sheldue to your operation sistem.

```
curl -L URL_OF_YOUR_SCRIPT
```

Add to the script

```
function doGet(e) {
    var result = {'status': 'ok'};
    try{
        main();
    }catch(err){
        result.['status'] = err;
    }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
 }
```

*You should [deploy your script as a Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps) for this.*

If you'll be use second sample you don't need Utilities.sleep(5000) more.

Best.